# How to write an Excel function which returns a value from an SQL database?

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I want to write the following function which should be used in an Excel worksheet:

```
=GetRecField("Foo Record Key", "FooField1")
```

...which will connect internally through ODBC to an SQL database, execute there an

```
SELECT FooField1 FROM MyTable WHERE KEY_FIELD='Foo Record Key';
```

and will return the resulting value as the result of the function GetRecField. The above SQL is granted to return only one record (IOW KEY_FIELD has an unique constraint).

Of course, the above function can be called multiple times in a worksheet so, please try to avoid a blind `QueryTables.Add`

TIA.

Comment: So, go ahead and write it.  It's not clear what exactly you're having trouble with.  Take a look at http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/ExternalData3.htm if you're totally lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a custom function to do that

1. Open the VBA editor (ALT-F11)
2. Open Tools -> References, and make sure the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library" are selected
3. Right click VBAProject, and choose Insert -> Module
4. Open the module. Now you can create a custom function, like:

```
    Public Function GetItem(field As String, id As Integer) As String
        Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Dim oRecordset As ADOR.Recordset
        oConnection.Open "provider=sqloledb;data source=yourserver;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;initial catalog=yourdatabase;"
        Set oRecordset = oConnection.Execute( & _
            "select " & field & " from table where id = " & id)
        If oRecordset.EOF Then
            GetItem = "n/a"
        Else
            GetItem = oRecordset(field)
        End If
    End Function
```

5. You can now call the function from a cell:

   =GetItem("fieldname";2)

The module is required because non-module functions can't be called from inside the spreadhseet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Excel's built-in database query functionality on a separate sheet (Data menu, Import External Data, New Database Query), then use `VLOOKUP` to extract values from that sheet?

Comment: because sometimes you dont want to issue unqualified searches that are either not allowed by the odbc source or may return more records than excel can handle

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in Excel version 1808(?) by saving the database connection in one sheet and using a reference to the desired cell in other sheets.

1. Data > Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server Database
2. Enter the Server and Database names.
3. Open Advanced options and enter the query verbatim, then name it "connection_name".
4. Now that the query is available, open Data > Queries & Connections.
5. Right click on the connection and click Load To...
6. Select an unused location on an unused sheet and put it there.
7. In the target cell elsewhere in the file, enter `=connection_name[[#All,][Column1]]`.

This certainly seems indirect in that I couldn't find a way to refer to the connection without it appearing in a sheet somewhere. But it worked for me and I wasn't able to find similar instructions elsewhere so I thought it could be informative.