# VBA Excel Is it possible to generate running alphanumeric numbers instead everytime i open the workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

i've recently have made a random 8digit ID Generator on my Form. But i was recommended to create a running alphanumeric number instead of the 8 random digit generator.. 
The file im currently using is a saved template for me to send to users. so i was wondering if it's possible to have a running alphanumber number everytime they opened the file. i just couldnt think of any way to "store a main cell where it can keep +1 on the previous code" because this template is not saved everytime i open but is to send to other users..

Or is there anyway where the file can check on my database for the next number to be sent and generate it on the form? Thanks..

Here is currently what i have for the 8 digit generator

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Called every time you open the excel document

    Dim myRandNumber As Long
    Randomize
    myRandNumber = CLng(Rnd() * 99999999)    ' CLng converts the floating point number to a long integer

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer
    rowNum = 6
    colNum = 4

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MySheetName).Cells(rowNum, colNum)
    If (.Value = "") Then
    .Value = myRandNumber
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW I'd recommend you use a GUID instead.

Comment: Why was it recommended to use a running alphanumeric number?  Simply to avoid collisions when two people generate the same random number?  If so, generate a GUID (using `Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 38)` ) and use that as your unique identifier.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - beat me!  (I actually recommended that last time this question was asked so, from that viewpoint, I beat you. :D )

Comment: An identifier such as `{72DE0025-2DC3-4691-9174-7DBDD2A52C62}` might look funny but, as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) says, "the number of random version 4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion" and "This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years".

Comment: @YowE3k , There's no need for such complicated ID. xD 
Something like 'A0000001' and follow by the running numbers

Comment: @user7809596 - But it is **hard** to generate something like `A0000001`, especially when the numbers are being generated in different versions of the spreadsheet.  It is **easy** to generate a GUID, and much, much, much less likely to have a collision.

Comment: Don't use random numbers for any sort of identifier. "Random" does not mean "unique". If you are using some sort of sequence then you will need concurrency controls so that everyone is picking from the same sequence (think of the ticket dispensing machine at a butcher's counter). Best solution, as others have suggested, is a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Just map digits or random numbers to characters, e.g. `Chr(65)` is `"A"`, etc. So the range is 65-90 for upper-case letters (English/Latin without diacritics)

At it's simplest, this would give a random letter (given limitations of Excel's/VBA's randomness, of course):

```
Chr(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(65,90))
```

The range for numerals is 48-57.

So develop a simple algorithm that chooses whether each is a digit or a character, and assign using the `Chr` function then joining them.

> i just couldnt think of any way to "store a main cell where it can keep +1 on the previous code"

Store it in a `Name` or a cell on a hidden worksheet.

> Or is there anyway where the file can check on my database for the next number to be sent and generate it on the form?

Possible, yes, but too broad a question. You can use VBA to connect to database using several methods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836065/how-to-write-an-excel-function-which-returns-a-value-from-an-sql-database) or see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e) for more possibilities. This will require more robust coding & error-handling -- what happens if user can't connect to the database, isn't on the network, etc...

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for the reply! I suddenly was told to come up with 3 alphaberts (Fixed alphaberts) and 5 numbers and running number that wont clash in the database.. is it possible to help me? e.g. ABC00001, ABC00002 and so on

Comment: @user7809596 you'll be better off with a GUID :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a userdefined function like

```
Function createCode(codelength As Integer) As String
  Dim x As Integer, iTemp As Integer
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Do Until i = codelength

    iTemp = Int(Rnd * 99)
    If iTemp >= 65 And iTemp <= 90 Then
    strTemp = strTemp & Chr(iTemp)
    i = i + 1
    ElseIf iTemp >= 97 And iTemp <= 122 Then
    strTemp = strTemp & Chr(iTemp)
    i = i + 1
    ElseIf iTemp >= 48 And iTemp <= 57 Then
    strTemp = strTemp & Chr(iTemp)
    i = i + 1
    End If
  Loop
  createCode = strTemp
End Function
```

that should be called like,

```
Sub caller()
    MsgBox createCode(8)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this as an answer, because it is (IMHO) the best answer to the **problem**, even if it isn't the best answer to the **question**.

Use a **[GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)**.

That will mean you are almost certainly guaranteed to not have a collision between generated IDs (unless you have several billion users opening copies of your workbook once every second for many years), and it is easy to do within Excel:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Update sheet name and range address as appropriate
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D6")
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
            .Value = Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 38)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I just got out-experienced by a true veteran. Thanks for this sir, I will be able to create an almost collision free code numbers.

Comment: @RomcelGeluz I found out about creating GUIDs when I was trying to dummy up some files for SSIS a couple of months ago.  They are perfect when there is a need to generate unique IDs, and Microsoft has made them extremely easy to create.  :)

Comment: i understand that GUID is the most effective one out there. But for this small task im assigned to, i'm tasked to have SCC00001 and the numbers continue on whenever i send the same template to the users of my group.. i really feel it's impossible but im just trying to ask here and see if there is any glimpse of hope.. thanks YowE3k, u have been answering my answers this past few days. really thankful

Comment: @ZQ7 If you need to have a sequentially assigned ID allocated to users, then you are either going to have to assign that number before you send them the workbook, or you are going to have to provide them with a method of accessing some central repository that keeps track of the next number to be allocated.  It isn't impossible, but it will be difficult.  The question to ask whoever is telling you that it needs to be sequential is ... "why does it need to be sequential, rather than random?"  The answer will probably be "to avoid potential collisions", but GUIDs solve that.

Comment: i think i know why, it because now i had created a template and database using TemplateWizard (WIZTEMPLT) 
So inside the template is a fillable form where i send to users and they have to fill up and send it back to me. the easy thing about template wizard is that just by a click of the save button, it will automatically send it to the database which i find it is really neat. So why they are requesting the ID is because they want to track it easily, and according to the numbers. E.g. earliest submited is SCC00001 so i can easily go to the form and check rather than random jumbled up numbers

Comment: Which is really hard to track back of the form

Comment: Once again, sorry for troubling you guys. really appreciate for your precious time

Comment: @ZQ7 If you (and not the users) are submitting the data, and you want to keep track of the order in which the data is submitted (not when the users opened the workbooks to fill in the data), then this becomes much easier.  You can just have a separate workbook that keeps a record of what number you are up to, and populate that number into the template before you submit it - the users don't need to know anything about what number has been assigned to all the other users.

Comment: So to do it manually? hehe. i would consider manually if really there is no other choice :/ @YowE3K

Comment: i just thought of something.. dont know if it will work. What if i were to create SCC00001 all those numbers in the database, and when i receive the file, just before i save. maybe i can use Workbook_Beforesave to lookup the database for the next blank beside the ID and if it's blank, look at the Left cell for the code and implement it on the form..? Just some thoughts but still new to VBA so cant really craft out :/

Comment: @ZQ7 I wasn't thinking manual - I was thinking a macro that looks up the current number from another workbook, increments it, stores the updated value back in the other workbook, uses that new number in your template, submits, saves.